# How to make Dynamic tables stack underneath each other? instead of just creating more data cells

Tags: javascript, html, css

Every time I add an item to my cart , which parses an object within a shopping cart array, It outputs the Item.name, item.price & item.qty but its just chaining them together, basically creating more data cells within the same table tag, how could I stop this and ensure each item has a new table made directly underneath each-other? (*I see sessionStorage is not allowed within this code snippet*).

```js
var shoppingCart = []; //{Product Name, Product Price}

var discountCoupon = "LINQ1234";

var vat = 1.15;

var totalCost = 0;

var delivery = 120;

var Item = function(name, price, qty){
 this.name = name;
 this.price = price;
 this.qty = qty;
};

function addItemToCart (name, price, qty) {
 var item = new Item(name, price, qty);
 shoppingCart.push(item);
 totalCost += item.price * item.qty * vat;
 sessionStorage.setItem("totalCost", JSON.stringify(totalCost));
 sessionStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(shoppingCart));
 alert("You have successfully added an item to your cart!, your current total is: R" + totalCost.toFixed(2) + " Including VAT.");
 return totalCost.toFixed(2);
};

function viewCart() { //output cart items to shopping cart HTML elements dynamically
 var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];
 var cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
 for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
  var a = document.createElement("td");
  a.innerHTML = cart[i].name;
  cartItems.appendChild(a);
  var b = document.createElement("td");
  b.innerHTML = cart[i].price;
  cartItems.appendChild(b);
  var c = document.createElement("td");
  c.innerHTML = cart[i].qty;
  cartItems.appendChild(c);
 }

};
```

```css
.item-in-cart {
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 15px;
}

.shoppingHeadings {
 text-align: center;
}

.cart-main-head {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.cartTotal {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="column col-md-3 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded shop-item">
  <h4 class="shop-item-name">Intel® Celeron® G4900</h4>
  <img class="shop-item-image" src="../Images/Celeron.gif">
  <ul class="shop-item-details">
   <li>Intel® Celeron® Processor G Series</li>
   <li>Cores : 2</li>
   <li>Threads : 2</li>
   <li>Base Frequency : 3.10GHz</li>
  </ul>
  <p class="shop-item-price">R699.00</p> 
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">More details</button>
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="addItemToCart('Intel Celeron G4900', 699, 1)">Add to cart</button>
</div>



<div class="container jumbotron shopping-cart">

 <h2 class="shoppingHeadings">Items in your cart:</h2>

 <br>

<div class="row item-in-cart">
 <table>
  <tr>
  <th>Item Name: </th>
  <th>Item Price: </th>
  <th>Item Quantity: </th>
  <tr>
 </table>
</div>

<!--First row of actual items-->

<div>
 <table class="row cart-items"> 
 </table>
</div>
<br>

<div class="shopping-cart-form"> 
 <form>
  Discount Coupon:
  <input id="discount-input" type="text" name="discount-coupon" autocomplete="off" onchange="discountCartTotal()">
 </form><br>
 <form>
  Collection:
  <input type="radio" name="collivery" value="Collection">
  Delivery:
  <input type="radio" name="collivery" value="Delivery">
 </form><br>
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger" onclick="clearCart()">Clear Cart</button> 
 <button class="btn btn-md btn-success" onclick="">Checkout</button> 
</div><br>

<div class="cartTotal">
 <p>Your total is :</p> 
</div>

</div>

<!--Ending of Main jumbotron DIV-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you found out already how to add table data to the table dynamically, it's not hard to understand, how to add a new table row for each item instead. Right now your code adds only table data to the table without any table rows. That wouldn't produce valid HTML.

I changed your output table a little bit for my example. In your code you have actually two tables but I think that's not what you want.

I added a sample array for the cart-items to make it work here. Please see the comments in the code example to understand, how I added the table data to the table row and the table row finally to the table.

```js
function viewCart() {
  /*var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0];*/
  var cartItems = document.getElementById('cart-items');

  /*var cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
  to make it work here, let's use a sample array for the cart items */
  var cart = [
    {
      'name': 'item1',
      'price': 24.99,
      'qty': 1
    },
    {
      'name': 'item2',
      'price': 12.99,
      'qty': 2
    }
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    /* create a new table row */
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    
    /* create td for item name */
    var a = document.createElement("td");
    a.innerHTML = cart[i].name;
    /* add td to table row */
    tr.appendChild(a);
    
    /* create td for item price */
    var b = document.createElement("td");
    b.innerHTML = cart[i].price;
    /* add td to table row */
    tr.appendChild(b);
    
    /* create td for item qty */
    var c = document.createElement("td");
    c.innerHTML = cart[i].qty;
    /* add td to table row */
    tr.appendChild(c);
    
    /* add table row to table #cartItems */
    cartItems.appendChild(tr);        
  }

};
```

```css
table td, th {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <table id="cart-items">
  <tr>
  <th>Item Name</th>
  <th>Item Price</th>
  <th>Item Quantity</th>
  <tr>
 </table>
</div>

<button onclick="viewCart()">
  show cart
</button>
```

If you really want to add a new table for each item, that would work similarly.